# Elasticsearch - range filter with multimatch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, search, filter

I'm using elastic search to filter outfits:

```
  def self.search(query)
  __elasticsearch__.search(
  {
    query: {
      function_score: {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['description^30','material^10']
          },
        },
        field_value_factor: {
          field: "purchased"
        },
      }
    }
  }
)
```

end

The problem is I can't seem to filter them by how many times they were purchased like this:

```
      range: {
              purchased: {
                gte: 1000
             }
      }
```

Wherever I put this, it gives me the following error:

```
[400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":88}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":88},"status":400}
```

How do I write the range filter properly/put the code? Is there somewhere I can read more about this to understand how the hash should should be arranged?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with a `bool/filter` query:

```
  def self.search(query)
  __elasticsearch__.search(
  {
    query: {
      function_score: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            filter: [
              {
                multi_match: {
                  query: query,
                  fields: ['description^30','material^10']
                }
              },
              {
                range: {
                  purchased: { gte: 1000}
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        field_value_factor: {
          field: "purchased"
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still get the same error. Is this definitely the correct syntax?

Comment: Please try again

Comment: Take out the very last comma. Does that to change how it's serialized when the request is passed to Elastic?